# Strange foreign Key error only on specific records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, doctrine, mysql-error-1064

I have a foreign key error using a status table.

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ID137594_gronden`.`project`, CONSTRAINT `project_fk_status` FOREIGN KEY (`statusID`) REFERENCES `status` (`id`)). Failing Query: "UPDATE project SET verkoperid = 1, adres = 'test 123', gemeenteid = 2121, statusid = '18', statusdescription = '123', oorsprongdossierint = 1, modifydate = '2016-09-28', manualdate = '2012-02-07', info = '1' WHERE (id = 449)"'

As you see I use statusID 18, updating the project and changing the status. I have 2 tables in this example, the project table and the status table. Within the status table the customer can manage the different statuses of a project. Within the project field they can add the correct status.
In the status table I have 18 records.

Now what is strange, only when using status with IDs 16, 17 en 18 give me this foreign key error. Using any other status, I have no issue.

How to get this solved?

Eric

Comment: Open the database using phpmyadmin or with some other UI. Check the relation of the project table once again. Is it defined correct? Is it referring the primary key of the status table, which is status id in your case? If yes, open the status table and see whether there is an entry like 16, 17, 18, etc...

Comment: Thanks, I went over the foreign key definitions in the database and found the issue. Working like a charm now.